# How to get immediate neighbors using a kd-tree irrespective of the spacing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, nearest-neighbor

I want to find the immediate neighbours around a given point in a multidimensional space (up to 7 dimensions).

**Important facts about the space:**

- **non-linear spacing** among points within a single dimension. As shown in the screenshot below, the distance between the points is varying
  [image: List item]
- **unequal spacing** among different dimensions

(sample code to generate a grid of uneven spacing among dimensions)

```
x_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)
y_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)
z_values = np.linspace(1, 6, 6) # unqual spacing (large spacing in z-direction)
```

**MWE:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np


# Define ranges for X, Y, and Z values
x_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)
y_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)
z_values = np.linspace(1, 6, 6) # unqual spacing (large spacing in z-direction)
# z_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5) # equal spacing case

# Create meshgrid to generate combinations of X, Y, and Z values
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values, z_values)

# Reshape the meshgrid arrays to create a single array of all combinations
points = np.column_stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()))

# Create a KDTree object with the sample points
kdtree = KDTree(points, leaf_size=30, metric='euclidean')

# Query point for which nearest neighbors will be found
# query_point = np.array([[0, 0, 0]]) # test query point for equal spacing
query_point = np.array([[0, 0, 2]]) # test query point for unequal spacing

# Find the indices of the nearest neighbors and their distances
distances, indices = kdtree.query(query_point, k=27)

# Plot all points in 3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], color='blue', label='All Points')

# Plot the query point in 3D
ax.scatter(query_point[:, 0], query_point[:, 1], query_point[:, 2], color='red', label='Query Point')

# Plot the nearest neighbors in 3D
nearest_neighbors = points[indices[0]]  # Get nearest neighbors using indices
ax.scatter(nearest_neighbors[:, 0], nearest_neighbors[:, 1], nearest_neighbors[:, 2], color='green', label='Nearest Neighbors')

# Connect the query point with its nearest neighbors in 3D
for neighbor in nearest_neighbors:
    ax.plot([query_point[0, 0], neighbor[0]], [query_point[0, 1], neighbor[1]], [query_point[0, 2], neighbor[2]], color='gray', linestyle='--')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('KD-Tree Nearest Neighbors in 3D')
ax.legend()
plt.show()

print()
```

**Results with the above Code:**

[image]

**Required results:** Immediate neighbors should be selected from each dimension irrespective their actual distance.

[image]

Comment: cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126971/55122

Answer (score 1):

The trick is generally to rescale the axis so that each axis contribute the same way to the distances used for the nn algo. More generally you can consider the scale of each axis as an hyper-parameter that you can tune to give more or less importance to a feature.

Then you have to 'go-back' to the original space for the original distances / plotings.  (go back with an inverse transform or simply get the indices and use the original data).

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np

# Define ranges for X, Y, and Z values
x_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)
y_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5)
z_values = np.linspace(1, 6, 6) # unqual spacing (large spacing in z-direction)
# z_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 5) # equal spacing case

# Create meshgrid to generate combinations of X, Y, and Z values
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values, z_values)

# Reshape the meshgrid arrays to create a single array of all combinations
points = np.column_stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel()))

# Create a KDTree object with the rescaled points
points_std = points.std(axis=0)
points_rescaled = points / points_std
kdtree = KDTree(points_rescaled, leaf_size=30, metric='euclidean')

# Query point for which nearest neighbors will be found
# query_point = np.array([[0, 0, 0]]) # test query point for equal spacing
query_point = np.array([[0, 0, 2]]) # test query point for unequal spacing

# Find the indices of the nearest neighbors and their distances
distances, indices = kdtree.query(query_point / points_std, k=27)

# Plot all points in 3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], color='blue', label='All Points')

# Plot the query point in 3D
ax.scatter(query_point[:, 0], query_point[:, 1], query_point[:, 2], color='red', label='Query Point')

# Plot the nearest neighbors in 3D
nearest_neighbors = points[indices[0]]  # Get nearest neighbors using indices
ax.scatter(nearest_neighbors[:, 0], nearest_neighbors[:, 1], nearest_neighbors[:, 2], color='green', label='Nearest Neighbors')

# Connect the query point with its nearest neighbors in 3D
for neighbor in nearest_neighbors:
    ax.plot([query_point[0, 0], neighbor[0]], [query_point[0, 1], neighbor[1]], [query_point[0, 2], neighbor[2]], color='gray', linestyle='--')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('KD-Tree Nearest Neighbors in 3D')
ax.legend()
plt.show()

print()
```

And the result in the original space:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Standardization. The result for the above case looks good, I will test it with my other scenario. But I wonder why not subtract the means to make it zero-centered. I tried that but it did not work, not sure why. Any comment on that?

Comment: In general I would suggest using a standard implementation (standard scaler from sklearn), that would indeed change the mean. (note: you can get creative with your embedding approach). But here centering doesn't matter, as it just shift all the point by the same constant, it doesn't change distances between points. (And also the data provided is already centered).

Comment: Unfortunately, this standardization process does not work if the number of points increases in one or two dimensions are increased. For example, if you use `x_values = np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, 50)` then, all the neighbours will be picked for the same y-coordinate.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. NN algo are based on a distance. I offered a trick to make the distance the same in direction. Now if you have a different (or additional) constraint, please state it clearly. It is not even clear what your end goal is.

Comment: note that if you have a regular grid you should be able to get the neighbor by incrementing the coordinates values....

Comment: I don't have any additional constraints. The screenshot showing neighbours in your answer is exactly what I need. The only problem is, if I increase the number of points in any dimension then, I am not getting the same neighbours as shown in your screenshot. I understand the Z-score normalization (your suggestion) would not work in this case, probably incrementing indices to build the adjacent neighbours is the way to go.

Comment: dividing by the step should work for the KDE tree then. However, as I mention you don't need a nn algo if you hae a regularly spaced grid.